# Admin page directing to 404 no route

Tags: admin

My site worked fine yesterday.  When I tried to log in this morning I get a 404 for the admin page.

May I ask for direction on why?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can get 404 on admin if there is no .htaccess file or url rewrite is disabled in configuration. Try this: `yoursite.tld/index.php/admin`

If you still get 404, check the admin router configuration in **app/etc/local.xml**

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Don't know what else it could be.

Comment: Yep that will do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Also check if there is a custom admin URL path in the database:

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path = 'admin/url/custom';
```